# Libgdx - Making a drop-down menu/settings screen

Tags: drop-down-menu, libgdx, settings

I'm looking to make a drop-down menu and drop-down settings screen but I couldn't find any resources for making these in Libgdx. Would like some pointers to good resources for this specific type of interface or a quick example.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by drop-down menu ? Are you looking for drop-down list, that allows one of a number of values to be chosen from a list ?

Comment: Yes, I mean a drop-down list. However I would also like a pop-up "menu", as in a new box screen that drops down, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

[SelectBox](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#selectbox) is in LibGDX can be used for drop-down list, it allows one of a number of values to be chosen from a list. And for pop-up window you can use `Dialog`.

```
stage=new Stage();

Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));

dialog=new Dialog("Setting",skin);
dialog.setSize(200,200);
dialog.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-100,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-100);

final SelectBox<String> selectBox=new SelectBox<String>(skin);
selectBox.setItems("XYZ","ABC","PQR","LMN");

dialog.getContentTable().defaults().pad(10);
dialog.getContentTable().add(selectBox);

stage.addActor(dialog);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Output

[image]