# Drop-down menu with title - libgdx

Tags: drop-down-menu, libgdx

I'm trying to implement a drop-down menu with Libgdx.
I already saw some topics about that but what I try to do was not mentionned.

For example in that question : [Libgdx - Making a drop-down menu/settings screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228190/libgdx-making-a-drop-down-menu-settings-screen)

What I want to do is the same, BUT with a title.
I mean, something like this : [image: Drop-down menu of Eclipse]
No need of the images on the left.

I already tried some things :

- With a Stack containing a Button and a SelectBox of String

  - The Button enable to hide the selected value of the selectBox
  - Everything is fine graphically, but the triggeredEvent is a ChangeEvent -> if I clic two times in a row on "New", no event is triggered.
- With a Stack containing a Button and a SelectBox of Button

  - The Button enable to hide the selected value of the selectBox
  - Everything is fine graphically, but when I clic on a button of the list of the SelectBox, nothing happens because what is drawn on screen is only the "toString() result" of my Button object and not the Button itself-> no event is triggered.

I'm not sure that what I want is possible with libgdx, because of the fact that this won't be very beautiful on a screen of Smartphone, but I just want to do a Desktop game, so... ^^'

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few months, I finally found a solution.

I create 2 instances of Button :

```
Button option1 = new Button();
Button option2 = new Button();
option1.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println("Do something 1");
    }
});
option2.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println("Do something 2");
    }
});
```

Then, a SelectBox of Button which contains these two buttons.

```
SelectBox<Button> selectBox = new SelectBox<>(skin);
selectBox.setItems(option1, option2);
```

In the SelectBox, I will have two possibilities.

Then, I want another button to be over the SelectBox "result". I create it and put it and the SelectBox in a Stack.

```
Button menuButton = new Button();
Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.add(selectBox);
stack.add(menuButton);
```

Everything is fine graphically, but it's what I mentionned in my question : nothing happens when I click on the options in the list.
But here is the new thing :

```
selectBox.getList().addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        for (EventListener eventListener: fileSelectBox.getSelected().getListeners()) {
            if (eventListenerinstanceof ClickListener) {
                ((ClickListener) eventListener).clicked(event, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And it's working. It seems that when we do :

```
selectBox.getSelected().getClickListener().clicked(event, x, y);
```

It doesn't send an event to a manually added ClickListener...

I hope it will help others!